How to transform messy excel sheet to time pivot table
I'm currently working on my thesis, which explores the impact of occupancy data on energy forecasts. I've received a dataset containing occupancy information for an entire year (please refer to the attached image). The dataset is in Dutch, where 'Personen' represents occupants, and 'Bezoekers' can be disregarded.
I aim to transform this dataset into a time pivot table spanning the entire year, updating hourly, so that I can utilize it in Python. However, I'm unsure where to begin with this process. Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you
enter image description here
Not much, I don't have much experience in this field. And I couldn't find any usefull videos

you could try looking at openpyxl, and when reading the excel sheet skip every other row and rows which don't contain "Personen" (the black rows) or if there's week average in cell A
